# STM32F4G-DISC1 and external oscillator does not work

Tags: microcontroller, stm32f4discovery

I got a problem. I have 2 STM32F407G-DISC1(MB997D) boards and I'm trying to configure it to blink user leds once at second with external oscillator. I configured timer(tim3) to work with external oscillator(ph0, ph1) in STM32CubeMx, but when I flash compiled code to the board and reset it then nothing happens. Same thing for both boards. What can be reason of this issue? Pictures below show my cubeMX configuaration:

[Pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5W7w.png)
[Clock configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TReU.png)

And code just toggles the leds.

```
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void)

    {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_IRQn 0 */

      /* USER CODE END TIM3_IRQn 0 */
      HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim3);
      /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_IRQn 1 */
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15);
      /* USER CODE END TIM3_IRQn 1 */
    }
```

Comment: This is pretty vague. I don't think you've given enough information for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: Not enough. Show us the timer 3 configuration and the part where you start the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. It is bug at stm32cubeMX. [Bugreport](https://community.st.com/thread/39340-bug-cubemx-v420-rcc-initialization-fail-with-hse-selected) you can see here.